# How to Change the Filename Prefix (DSC) of Camera Photos

Tags: camera

I have a android mobile with 5 MP camera. I use the default camera app to capture photos.

All the pictures captured by camera has DSC prefix in their name - DSC_XXXX.
I want to remove DSC prefix and add the date prefix in `DEFAULT CAMERA APPLICATION`

How to do it ?

Comment: A possible solution is using [Tasker][1] or some equivalent to rename the files. Would that be acceptable? (I'll write up a more in-depth answer, if so)

Comment: I second the Tasker idea.

Comment: I third it *LOL* Shouldn't be too long, but why invent the wheel again. So please elaborate, @Jeeva!

Comment: I am struggling to find a way to do this with tasker ;)

Comment: @LiamW - Tasker won't trigger off a "picture taken" event AFAICT.  I'm seeing a partway solution (Trigger tasker off the camera app start to get the current time (%TIMES), then trigger it again off the camera app exit to go into the DCIM folder and rename anything newer than the previously saved time.), but I can't figure out a way to edit the filename in that manner rather than appending or wholly replacing the existing filename.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that since it has been coded in program level you can't change the prefix DSC in all photos. You need to have the code for the apk and change the prefix string and build an apk then only you can do that cheers......